Configure an Apache2 webserver to get a 504 code
I am trying to configure my apache2 webserver in a way, that I will get a 504 http code.
I've configured my apache2 webserver as follows:
<VirtualHost *:80>

    # Configure the proxy
    ProxyPass /slow http://localhost:5000/slow
    ProxyPassReverse /slow http://localhost:5000/slow

    # Set a low timeout to trigger the 504 error
    ProxyTimeout 1
    Timeout 1
</VirtualHost>

Then, I've configured a python webserver using flask:
from flask import Flask
import time

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/slow')
def slow():
    time.sleep(300)  # Sleep for 5 minutes
    return "This response is slow!"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=5000)

Unfortunately, when I start my flask webserver, and when I request 127.0.0.1/slow, all I get is a 502 http code.

Solved:
You need to add also:
<Proxy "*">
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Proxy>

<Location /your-location>
    ProxyPass http://localhost:5000/slow
    ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:5000/slow
</Location>

Then, shutdown your flask webserver (you actually don't need it), and then you will get a 504 response
